# QueueManager.Disconnect() and QueueManager.Close() Difference?

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, mq

I have a code which disconnects queuemanger when the connection is broken or exception is thrown like below

```
            if (queueManagerreceive != null)
            if (queueManagerreceive.IsConnected)
            {
                if (queuereceive != null)
                {
                    queuereceive.Close();
                }
                queueManagerreceive.Disconnect();
            }
```

So i have issue with the above code when i have a  'MQRC_RECONNECT_TIMED_OUT' 
exception then when it does a queuemanager.Disconnect() it throws an exception "MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN" and obviously which breaks the code as an exception is thrown  so when i use queuemanager.Close() there was no exception thrown and the service was stable.

What is the difference? what should i use to drop and recreate a new connection?

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

The `MQQueueManager.Disconnect()` closes all queues/topics/processed opened and closes the connection to queue manager. Calling `Disconnect()` on an already disconnected connection helps in freeing any resources allocated internally.

`MQQueueManager.Close` method is actually an inherited method of it's base class and this method closes any internal objects the `MQQueueManager` has allocated. . But you must always call `Disconnect` instead of `Close` because the `Disconnect` method closes the connection to queue manager while `Close` does not.

After `MQRC_RECONNECT_TIMED_OUT` error you have to create a new connection again using new MQQueueManager constructor.

You are getting a `MQRC_RECONNECT_TIMED_OUT` error which means that an established connection was broken (for whatever reason) and the MQ client attempted to reconnect for 30 minutes but still could not establish connection. You have to understand the reasons for this:

1) Is your queue manager down for that long?

2) Is there a network issue which is preventing connection to queue manager?

3) If your are using a multi-instance queue manager, why application is not getting connected to stand-by instance?

Comment: Thank you for giving me a clear idea on disconnect and close. There was a network interruption for 5 min but still the queue manager it didn't reconnect. But i tried to test it with network down for longer time so when a MQRC_RECONNECT_TIMED_OUT exception was thrown and i tried to use MQQueueManager.Disconnect(); it didn't free the resources. it threw an exception at  MQQueueManager.Disconnect(); and the service just went idle. what should be the scenario? what is that am doing wrong?

Comment: How did you determine resources were not freed? what exception was thrown? Can you update your question with all details?

Comment: No details provided on what exception was thrown. But in any case if you have received a MQRC_RECONNECT_TIMED_OUT, then you will need to create fresh connection to queue manager again.

Comment: "MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN" exception was thrown. and yes am creating a fresh connection after any exception but before creating a fresh connection i have a queuemanager.disconnect() where "MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN" exception was thrown.